# Does anyone have High resolution Buddha wallpapers for computer?

Tags: meditation, buddha

Please feel free to delete this question if not relevant.
I want to find peaceful Buddha statue wallpaper (Drawing or Statue). I wish to see lockscreen and my desktop with a spiritual wallpaper of lord Buddha. I feel peace in mind whenever I see lord Buddha. But across the google, etc. search engines point me to commercial sites. If any of you have good high resolution wallpaper, please share the location to download. much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [There are some pictures](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8022.0.html) dedicated for the Sangha and a monastery. Try btw .how it feels and gives peace following [this](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/bettertogive_en.html).

Comment: Have you tried Google Images, DeviantArt, Pinterest?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried these links [pinterest](https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=Buddha&rs=typed&term_meta[]=Buddha%7Ctyped), [guoguiyan](http://www.guoguiyan.com/buddha-wallpapers.html), [desktop-screens](http://www.desktop-screens.com/buddhism-wallpapers.html)